# WebDriverException: impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

I've checked the other answers around this question, but didn't find a solution that works.

I am not sure, but I think this is due to the capabilities being malformed, but I haven't found anywhere that gives what the correct caps should be.

The node registers fine, launches the app on an iOS devices, but then just stops there giving the errors found in the logs below.

I get a 200 response from the server, but in the device log I'm seeing the error above, along with some additional 'illegal keys' error around 'platform' capability.

Here's my stats:

```
Appium server: 1.9.2beta.2
Appium java-client: 6.1.0
Selenium grid and java client: 3.14.0 (I've tried the latest 3.141.59 
but no luck)
iOS device is a real iPad, running iOS 12.1
Mac OSX: Mojave
Xcode: 10.1
```

Here's the relevant portion of the device log (apologies for formatting):

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a 
new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, 
InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    Build info: version: '3.14.0', 
revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    System info: host: '<hostRA>', ip: 
'10.0.14.9', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0- 
862.3.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.
createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:195)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.
createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:209)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.
execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 

org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute
(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute
(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute
(AppiumDriver.java:1)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute
(IOSDriver.java:1)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 

org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession
(RemoteWebDriver.java:212)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init> . 
(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init> . 
(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:95)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
cucumber.driver.Factory.createPlatformDriver(Factory.java:54)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
cucumber.driver.Factory.createDriverWithLatestAppBuild
(Factory.java:36)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
cucumber.driver.Factory.createDriverWithApp(Factory.java:31)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
cucumber.support.Hooks.beforeScenario(Hooks.java:55)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 build  16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 

sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 

cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute
(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00        at 
cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
...
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    Caused by: 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to parse remote 
response: <html>
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    <head>
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    <title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    </head>
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    <p>Problem accessing /wd/hub/session. 
Reason:
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:00    <pre>    Server Error</pre></p> . 
<h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.io.IOException: 
org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Cannot extract a 
capabilities from the request: {
  &quot;desiredCapabilities&quot;: {
  &quot;app&quot;: &quot;\u002f<APPNAME>.ipa&quot;,
  &quot;appium:udid&quot;: &quot;<UDID>&quot;,
  &quot;newCommandTimeout&quot;: 10000,
  &quot;xcodeOrgId&quot;: &quot;<XCODEID>&quot;,
 &quot;appium:deviceName&quot;: &quot;iPad&quot;,
 &quot;platformName&quot;: &quot;iOS&quot;,
  &quot;appium:automationName&quot;: &quot;XCUITest&quot;,
  &quot;appium:platformVersion&quot;: &quot;12.1&quot;,
 &quot;platform&quot;: &quot;MAC&quot;,
 &quot;xcodeSigningId&quot;: &quot;iPhone Developer&quot;,
  &quot;wdaLocalPort&quot;: 8108
 },
&quot;capabilities&quot;: {
&quot;alwaysMatch&quot;: {
&quot;appium:app&quot;: &quot;\u002f<APPNAME>&quot;,
&quot;appium:automationName&quot;: &quot;XCUITest&quot;,
&quot;appium:deviceName&quot;: &quot;iPad&quot;,
&quot;appium:platformVersion&quot;: &quot;12.1&quot;,
&quot;appium:udid&quot;: &quot;<UDID>&quot;,
 &quot;appium:newCommandTimeout&quot;: 10000,
&quot;platform&quot;: &quot;MAC&quot;,
&quot;platformName&quot;: &quot;ios&quot;,
&quot;appium:wdaLocalPort&quot;: 8108,
&quot;appium:xcodeOrgId&quot;: &quot;<ORGID>&quot;,
&quot;appium:xcodeSigningId&quot;: &quot;iPhone Developer&quot;
},
&quot;firstMatch&quot;: [
{
      }
]
}
 }
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: 
<. Last 1 characters read: <
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:01    Build info: version: '3.14.0', 
revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
build   16-Nov-2018 17:45:01    System info: host: '93deac6ef15a', ip: 
'10.0.14.9', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0- 
862.3.2.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
 build  16-Nov-2018 17:45:01    Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
```

Comment: hi, I haven't tried appium 1.9 yet but I wonder what are `xcodeOrgId` and `xcodeSigningId` mean. Are those new capabilities introduced in appium 1.9?

Comment: BTW, can you show your pom? i think it's a change of selenium. For sure I see `createSession` in selenium-remote-driver.3.12.0 but it can be changed in different version